# Is 吾 a joyo kanji?

Tags: kanji, jōyō-kanji

I was trying to learn the joyo kanji, which if I understand correctly is a list of kanji listed in a guide by the Japanese ministry of education or something like that. By recommendation, I'm taking a look at the "learning the kanji" book, which helps memorize kanji and meanings, but it gives no info about their pronunciation (or at least it doesn't from what I've read). The book lists the kanji in this picture (which is a simple kanji if you consider the number of strokes) , it is one of the kanji for a widely used word "I" , but I can't find it in the joyo kanji list. Is this some sort of "unofficial" kanji or something like that, or I do I have an incomplete list of joyo kanji? (or am I plain dumb and I can't find it?)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[No.](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%90%BE%20%23kanji) It's a [Jinmeiyou kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinmeiy%C5%8D_kanji) (which means it's used in names but isn't a Joyo kanji).